# Redirect website to different languages using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, subdirectory

I have a website that has designed in 2 languages; English and Persian.
Directory structure is like this:

```
root
 |-- en directory
     |-- index.php
 |-- index.php (For Persian edition)
 |-- .htaccess
```

I want to redirect users temporary to **en/index.php** if they enter the website URL only without mention to any special directory or file. But when user goes to **en** edition, he must be able to go to **Persian** edition using the appropriate link like this:

```
<a href="www.site.com/index.php">Persian</a>
```

What do I need to put in .htaccess for this goal?

Comment: I do not understand how your url's for the Persian version look like and how your url's for the English version look like. How do you intend to 'remember' what language the user wants?

Comment: Probably the better approach is to define a "user language" inside the server side user session. That language can be set by a request argument specified in the link to switch the language. That way when rendering content you only have to check the language inside the session and include different templates and translate text tokens to a different language.

Comment: Why does a simple `RewriteRule ^$ /en/index.php [R,L]` not work?

Comment: @Sumurai8 I think in this case whenever I click on Persian link, I will go to English version again and again ...

Comment: That rule would only match if the path is empty (e.g. when you go to `www.example.com`). Any other url will not match, and thus will not be redirected.

Comment: I tested it. When I wanted to enter to Persian version, it redirected again to English version

Comment: You'll need to put actual url's in your question then: How the links look like in the English version, how the urls look like in the Persian version. The url you put in your question (`www.site.com/index.php`) does not match my rule and shouldn't be redirected, unless you have rules you are not telling us about.

Comment: Use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ...`?